# compare arrays integer values with shifted values

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I want create function which compares two arrays so that if they have the same values in a certain order (which may be maybe shifted) returns `true`.

For example

```
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
int arr2[] = {3,4,5,1,2}
```

are the same, or `true`

while

```
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5}
int arr2[] = {3,4,5,2,1}
```

are not same, and so `false`.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you want to check if `arr1` and `arr2` have the same contents irregardless of order?

Comment: @yano the edit says (implies) it is rotated, otherwise same order.

Comment: What is your question please?

Comment: Did you write any code or tried to at least? If yes please do post it to help us help you.

Comment: ohh, got it. Well my first un-optimized instinct would just be to rotate `arr1` by one, then `memcmp` with `arr2` .. rinse and repeat until you find a match or rotate the length of `arr1`. I'm sure there's a more optimal solution, however. First thing, check that `arr1` and `arr2` are the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_equivalent(const int a[], const int b[], size_t n)
{
    int success = 0;

    for ( size_t m = 0; !success && m < n;  )
    {
        // Try to find in the array a the first element of the array b
        // If there is no such an element then the arrays are different.
        // Otherwise compare elements of the arrays starting from the
        // found element in a and the first element in b
        while (m < n && a[m] != b[0]) ++m;

        if (m != n)
        {
            size_t i = 1;
            size_t j = ++m % n;

            while (i < n && b[i] == a[j])
            {
                ++i; ++j;
                j %= n;
            }

            success = i == n;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

int main( void )
{
    {
        int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int b[] = { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 };

        printf("The arrays are equivalent: %d\n",
            is_equivalent(a, b, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)));
    }

    {
        int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int b[] = { 3, 4, 5, 2, 1 };

        printf("The arrays are equivalent: %d\n",
            is_equivalent(a, b, sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The arrays are equivalent: 1
The arrays are equivalent: 0
```

Comment: @Paul You are right. But it is enough to add an external loop and the function will work for any arrays.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You need to find where the second array starts in the first array. To do that you need to find the first element of the second array in the first array and then starting with the found position to compare all elements of the arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this code could be simplified quite a lot. You could simply leave the loop for calculating the offset away and wouldn't need to check if `m < n` before the comparison without altering the functionality at all. It's brute-force, but it works. As for the explanation: I think what JohnKugelman meant was that you should add comments to the question. Personally I don't have a problem with understand the code, but I doubt OP will cope with this that easy.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check(size_t size, int arr1[], int arr2[]){
    int *temp = malloc(size * 2 * sizeof *temp);
    memcpy(temp, arr1, size * sizeof *temp);
    memcpy(temp+size, arr1, size * sizeof *temp);//[1,2,3] --> [1,2,3,1,2,3]

    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if(memcmp(temp+i, arr2, size * sizeof *temp) == 0)
            break;
    free(temp);
    return i != size;
}    

#define TEST(size, a1, a2) puts(check(size, a1, a2) ? "same" : "not same")

int main(void) {
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr2[] = {3,4,5,1,2};
    int arr3[] = {3,4,5,2,1};
    int arr4[] = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    int arr5[] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    size_t size = sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(*arr1);

    TEST(size, arr1, arr2);
    TEST(size, arr1, arr3);
    TEST(size, arr4, arr5);
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.  Just because the question is poor and vague doesn't mean that the answer should be terse and uninformative!

Comment: It is almost self explanatory, so there is no need to add further explanation.

Comment: @Paul Sure. I changed the algorithm.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY looks fine to me. Though it's just the bruteforce-search which OP wanted to avoid...

Comment: `memcmp` is not to search exhaustively every time.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so what do you think `memcmp` does? It's a tweaked exhaustive search under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the arrays are just rotated versions of each other, they must be of equal length and there must exist at least one offset, such that `rotate(arr1, offset) == arr2`.

Thus we know that `concat(arr2, arr2)` must be equivalent to `rotate(concat(arr1, arr1), offset)` and thus must contain `arr1` without rotation at position `offset`.

And there we are with the classical substring-matching problem. There won't be any better solution to this problem than the algorithms to solve the former simply because they are equivalent.

A pretty simple solution to this problem would be elimination of probable offsets:

```
//generate a list of offsets from the first element in arr1
list offsets = indicesOf(arr1[0], arr2)

int i = 0
while !offsets.empty && i < length(arr1):
    //generate the rotational offsets of the next char
    list nextoffsets = indicesOf(arr1[i], arr2)
    //make offsets the list of offsets that are valid for all elements up to arr1[i]
    offsets = intersection(offsets, nextoffsets)

    i++

return !offsets.empty
```

Comment: I think you're missing the headers that declare those functions - are they in `<algorithm>`?  Actually, they can't be, because this is C, not C++.

Comment: @TobySpeight This is obviously a homework question. I'm willing to throw in an approach to solve the problem and a bit of help understanding the problem, but not more. As for the headers: this is pseudocode, not an actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isArraySame(int arr1[], int arr2[], int len1, int len2){
    int var1=0;
    int var2=0;
    int index=0;

    for (index=0;index<len1;index++){
        var1+=arr1[index];
    }

    for (index=0;index<len2;index++){
        var2+=arr2[index];
    }

    if (var1==var2) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr2[] = {3,4,5,1,2};
    if (isArraySame(arr1, arr2, 5, 5)) {
        printf("true");
    } else {
        printf("false");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well... no, I'm sorry. Please, consider what your function will return in case of `int arr1[] = {1,1,1}; int arr2[] = {3};` or `int arr1[] = {-1,2,1}; int arr2[] = {1,1,0};`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the C++ equivalent for this.  It's instructive to see how the Standard Library provides much higher-level abstractions than are available to the C programmer.

First of all, we'll want a sensible signature for our function.  Let's make it a template, so we can use `std::array` as happily as `std::vector` and `struct Foo` as happily as `int`:

```
template<typename T>
bool equals_rotated(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b);
```

And some simple tests:

```
int main()
{
    const auto e = equals_rotated<int>;
    return !e({}, {})
        +   e({1, 2, 3, 4} , {1, 2, 3})
        +  !e({1, 2, 3}    , {1, 2, 3})
        +   e({1, 2, 3, 4} , {1, 2, 4, 3})
        +  !e({1, 2, 3, 4} , {4, 1, 2, 3})
        ;
}
```

The implementation is straightforward.  We know that if the arrays differ in length then they can't be equivalent; conversely, if they are identical, they must be equivalent.  So let's return early in those cases:

```
if (a.size() != b.size())
    return false;
if (a == b)
    return true;
```

For the general case, we can make a concatenation of `a` and itself, and then test whether that contains `b` as a subsequence.  This will have an impact on the memory requirement, but it makes for a simple implementation:

```
auto v = a;
v.reserve(2*a.size());
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
return std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), b.begin(), b.end()) != v.end();
```

---

If we put that all together, include the necessary headers, and add a wrapper so that we can call it from C, we get:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename IterA, typename IterB>
bool equals_rotated(IterA a_begin, IterA a_end, IterB b_begin, IterB b_end)
{
    // trivial tests
    if (a_end - a_begin != b_end - b_begin)
        return false;
    if (std::equal(a_begin, a_end, b_begin, b_end))
        return true;
    // Otherwise, make a copy of a+a
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<IterA>::value_type> v;
    v.reserve(2 * (a_end - a_begin));
    const auto ins = std::back_inserter(v);
    std::copy(a_begin, a_end, ins);
    std::copy(a_begin, a_end, ins);
    // and test whether it contains b
    return std::search(v.begin(), v.end(), b_begin, b_end) != v.end();
}

template<typename T>
bool equals_rotated(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    return equals_rotated(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
}

extern "C" {
    bool is_rotated_array(int *a, size_t a_len, int *b, size_t b_len)
    {
        return equals_rotated(a, a+a_len, b, b+b_len);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const auto e = equals_rotated<int>;
    return !e({}, {})
        +   e({1, 2, 3, 4} , {1, 2, 3})
        +  !e({1, 2, 3}    , {1, 2, 3})
        +   e({1, 2, 3, 4} , {1, 2, 4, 3})
        +  !e({1, 2, 3, 4} , {4, 1, 2, 3})
        ;
}
```